# Is it possible to get all the values from the DataValue fields of a Dropdown List in to an Array?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to get all the values from the DataValue fields of a Dropdown List in to an Array ? Im trying to store the DataValues in to an Array and use it later for some verification purpose.

```
DropDownList dropDownList = new DropDownList();
dropDownList.ID = "dropDownEmployees";
dropDownList.DataSource = sqlDS;
dropDownList.DataTextField = "Employee";
dropDownList.DataValueField = "Employee_Name";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] values = dropDownList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                              .Select(i => i.Value)
                              .ToArray();
```